# Build a DataFrame with given set of columns while copying value from another DataFrame with duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I am given a DataFrame `df1` with columns `['A', 'B', 'C']`, and another list of columns labels, like `cols = ['A', 'B', ..., 'Z']`, among which the label may or may not also be column of `df1`. My goal is to build a DataFrame `df` with columns of `cols`, and if any column label in `df1` also exists in `cols`, this column will be copied into `df`. My solution is like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=cols)
for c in cols:
    if c in df1:
        df[c] = df1[c]
```

This works, but I am wondering if there is any more pandas-ish way to accomplish it. I don't mind the values of other columns to be NaN.

Comment: just to add a comment that `df1` may also contain column labels that are not in `cols`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html?highlight=reindex#pandas.DataFrame.reindex):

```
df = df1.reindex(columns=cols)
```